# ResourceLoader and Neutral Language

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to localize my Windows Store app. I have string\cs-CZ\Resources.resw and I load the strings in C# using ResourceLoader. When I have my system set to cs-CZ locale, the string are returned ok. When I set to to another locale, the GetString method returns an empty string. I have my projects neutral solution set to cs-CZ so what is the problem? How do I make the app always take resources from string\cs-CZ\Resources.resw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default locale can be programatically set using

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "cs-CZ";
```

in `OnLaunched`